# Different reference number styles at end of sentence and at endnote/footnote

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I'm using endnotes in a MS Word 2011 doc, so I have references at the end of sentence and at the end of the document (with corresponding numbers). Both corresponding numbers have the same style — "endnote reference" — that puts the number in superscript.

I would like to uncouple or separate the corresponding numbers so that they can use different styles (i.e., turn off superscript in the endnote numbers). As it stands, changing "endnote reference" changes the style for both the numbers at the end of the sentence and in the endnote. How do I set my reference numbers to use two different styles, or otherwise get the formatting I want?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't actually change the style of the endnote numbering.  However there is a workaround.  It is adviseable to do this after all the endnotes have been inserted into the document:
1. Sit your cursor at the beginning of the endnotes.
2. Press control+H to display the find and replace dialogue box.
3. In the "find what" enter: ^02 
   (this specifies to look for footnote references)
4. In the replace with box enter: ^&
  (this specifies that you are replacing what is found with whatever is found in the "find what" box)
5. Click the format botton choose font and uncheck the superscript tickbox. 
6. Click okay and click replace all.
7. When word asks you if you want to search from the beginning of the document click no (as otherwise it will change all the superscript references to normal text within the document).